# Having sum problems, xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, sum, xslt-1.0

I've been trying to get the total amount spent by a user on products but with no success.
  Given the following XML sample, the total amount spent by the *client 1* would be 21,00 but i'm getting 10,50 (this only happens if the client buys many times the same product, if he buys different products the returning amount is the expected)

XML sample:

```
<root>
            <sale id="1">
                <date>2014-01-01</date>
                <client>1</client>
            </sale>

            <sale id="2">
                <date>2014-01-02</date>
                <client>1</client>
            </sale>

            <sale_details saleID="1">
                <product id="1"/>
            </sale_details>

            <sale_details saleID="2">
                <product id="1"/>
            </sale_details>

            <product_details productID="1">
                <name>product x</name>
                <price>10.50</price>
            </product_details>

            <product_details productID="2">
                <name>product x</name>
                <price>5.26</price>
            </product_details>

            <client_detail clientID="1">
                <name>client 1</name>
            </client_detail>

            <client_detail clientID="2">
                <name>client 2</name>
            </client_detail>
    </root>
```

XSLT sample:

```
<xsl:template name="sum-spent-amount">
    <xsl:param name="clientID"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//gv:product_details[@productID=//gv:sale_details[@saleID=//gv:sale[gv:client=$clientID]/@id]/gv:product/@id]/gv:price)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you're getting a result of 10.5: you are summing the **unique** instances of the sold products. You must sum the prices of the actual sales. Here's one way to do it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="clientID" select="1"/>

<xsl:key name="sale-by-clientID" match="sale" use="client" />
<xsl:key name="sale_detail-by-saleID" match="sale_details" use="@saleID" />
<xsl:key name="product-by-id" match="product_details" use="@productID" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="mySaleIDs" select="key('sale-by-clientID', $clientID)/@id" />
    <xsl:variable name="prices">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('sale_detail-by-saleID', $mySaleIDs)">
            <price><xsl:value-of select="key('product-by-id', product/@id)/price"/></price>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <sum><xsl:value-of select="sum(exsl:node-set($prices)/price)"/></sum>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to your input, the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sum>21</sum>
```

Comment: Hey @michael.hor257k, thank you for your fast answer.
Could this possibly be achieved without exsl?

Comment: @vitor Possibly, but why? I don't know of any XSLT 1.0 processor that doesn't support exsl:node-set().

Comment: I've read about that but this is for a college project, i must use what has been taught, I've been trying but i can't get the right solution.

Comment: @vitor To do this in pure XSLT 1.0, you must use a recursive template and loop over the `sale_details` that are associated with the given client id. Let each one of these fetch the relevant price from the related product, and add it to the result.

Comment: Thank you for the description of the algorithm! I'll try to learn more about recursive template.

Comment: If your college course is teaching XSLT 1.0, that seems very odd. It's been superseded over seven years ago. There might be good reasons in industry for using obsolete technology, but teaching it on a college course seems a very strange decision.

Answer (score 0):

**I got to this solution using recursive template:**

The template:

```
<xsl:template name="sum">

    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="total" select="0"/>

    <xsl:variable name="current" select="$nodes[1]" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$current">              
            <xsl:variable name="product" select="//gv:product_details[@productID=$current/gv:product/@id]"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="sum">

                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() &gt; 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$total + $product/gv:price"/>

            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$total"/></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

Using the template here:

```
<xsl:variable name="clientID" select="1"/>
<xsl:call-template name="sum">
    <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="//gv:sale_details[@saleID=//gv:sale[gv:client=clientID]/@id]" />
</xsl:call-template>
```